# Classification of finite subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}_5(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: gr.group-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$I would like to know if there is a full list of isomorphic class of finite subgroups of $\SL_5(\mathbb{C})$. I have already found the classification for $\SL_2$ and $\SL_3$. Thank you very much!

Comment: Incidentally, what is the classification for SL3? I only know the SL2 case.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd: See H.F. Blichfeldt,  The finite, discontinuous, primitive groups of collineations in three variables. Math. Ann. 63 (1907), no. 4, 552–572.

Comment: I think the original result for SL3 is due to Camille Jordan https://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN00215675X

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam: Blichfeldt credits Jordan but points out that Jordan missed two perfect subgroups of $SL_3(C)$, namely $GL_3(2)$ and $3A_6$, of orders $168$ and $1080$.

Comment: Since you did not restrict to irreducible groups, you also need the list of irreducible finite subgroups of ${\rm GL}(4, \mathbb{C})$ in addition to the groups given in Richard's answer. These groups were also know  to Blichfeldt (at least the primitive ones). There  were some omissions/errors, eg one found by Conway.

Comment: There is a helpful list of low dimensional finite complex linear groups in the article by W.Feit in the Proceedings of the 1970 ICM, held in Nice.

Comment: @RichardLyons: yes. It seems that even Blichfeldt missed some subgroups too, as per Yau and Yu in "Gorenstein Quotient Singularities in Dimension Three" https://bookstore.ams.org/memo-105-505 That's quite a tricky problem.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam:Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam: If I'm reading correctly, Blichfeldt did not miss any collineation groups, i.e., subgroups of $PSL_3(C)$.

Answer (score 13):

The irreducible primitive finite subgroups of $SL_5(C)$ were classified up to isomorphism by Richard Brauer:  "[Über endliche lineare Gruppen von Primzahlgrad](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01399532)", Math. Ann. 169 (1967), 73–96.

Comment: By the way,  believe that some of the groups in Brauer's list are actually imprimitive : for example, the $5$ dimensional character of $A_{5}$ is induced from any non-trivial linear character of $A_{4}.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson That is a slightly unusual example of an imprimitive group in that it acts faithfully on the blocks, so its kernel is trivial.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: Thanks for the clarification.